# How does Activerecord 'knows' which adapter it should use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm quite new to Rails and its internals and I'm wondering how does Activerecord 'knows' which adapter it should use?
I know when you create a rails project you can set the database you gonna use like `rails new project -d mysql`. 
I was trying to find out how it works on Activrecord's code but I got overwhelmed and I couldn't find where the magic happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an idea for how Rails adapts to different databases by checking out Ryan Bates's RailsCast on migrating from Sqlite3 to Postgres.

Read the *Migrating an Existing Application* section: http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql?view=asciicast

As you'll see, the magic happens in the `database.yml` file. Whichever adapter is present in those settings is the one Rails will use.

For a more in-depth look at the code that handles this, check out the [`activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b189f2846ada47a1b8094625fd7b30b3f32714d7/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb) file.

Comment: Great, the connection_specification.rb is what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It's set in config/database.yml file

`Database.yml` is configuration file which tells rails about database, database information such as

1. database host/machine
2. which database to choose ( mySQL, Oracle, Sqlite... etc)
3. Username
4. password

[More about database.yml](http://rubyinrails.com/2014/01/database-yml-rails/)

Comment: Yes, this part I got. My doubt was where in Activerecord's code this connector is picked. But thanks for the answer anyway :)